# Display two columns with CSS, one with fixed width and another to take the rest of space

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm just trying to get into the benefits of using CSS vs. tables, but so far I'm not convinced. Something that I could do within a minute with a table seems to be not so easy with CSS (at least for me at this point.) So, this question is not about merits of using CSS vs. tables. I need to know how to do the following with CSS:

Say, I have an encompassing element that needs to be separated in two columns, so to speak:

```
<div id="idOuter">
 <div id="idLeft"></div>
 <div id="idRight"></div>
<div>
```

idLeft element must be of a fixed width. For instance, 100px. It will contain a text label with a margin. But the idRight must occupy whatever width is left in the idOuter div. It will contain a text input element with a margin. The idOuter should also reflect the height of both idLeft and idRight and have its own margin.

So how do you do it? I keep messing with floats and inline-blocks and widths but it always comes out messed up when I resize the browser window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's relatively easy - http://jsfiddle.net/bWuQB/5/

```
#idOuter {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#idLeft {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background: orange;
    position: absolute;
}

#idRight {
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: beige;
}
```

And you have to forget about using tables for layouts and anything, but tabular data. When you get used to table-less layouts you'll like them. And semantically it's the correct solution.

**EDIT: Removed unnecessary float statement and updated Fiddle**

Comment: Well, it's easy for you :) Thanks.

Comment: It will become easy for you in no time :) just start and you'll see

Comment: @ahmd0 just so you know here, the "magic" behind this solution is absolute positioning.  Keep that in mind when/if you do any follow-up reading.  If you remove the `float:left;` statement from `#idLeft`, it will still render properly, because it's not being used.  Just trying to avoid confusion.

Comment: This might not work reliably cross-browser unless #idOuter is given a fixed height. Without that, the browser will be trying to calculate the height of both #idOuter and the columns based on 100% of the height of the other (i.e., 100% of what? 100% of 100%...).

Comment: What I'm finding is that, if #idOuter doesn't have a fixed height, it takes on the height of the last column (which is either good or bad depending on which column has taller content). Tested in FF, Chrome, IE9.

Comment: Taking the jsfiddle and swapping the content for the two columns, you can see the container height ends up too short: http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/2zext/1/

Comment: Guys, sorry to bring this up again. But what if I put some other element instead of the right div. Like a text input? http://jsfiddle.net/bWuQB/15/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've seen (and I've done some looking), the best implementation (*not using javascript*) uses a combination of floats and margins to achieve the fixed-fluid layout you desire.  Even in this implementation however, **the containing div still won't reflect the proper height 100% of the time.**

[Fiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/eHGBX/)

[[source]](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/)

Comment: credit goes to @Dirk de Man for posting the link.  This is only here because he never posted an answer...

Comment: Thanks for posting it. So just from curiousity, if doing this simple layout with CSS poses so many issues why are people bad-mouthing using tables to do this layout?

Comment: I think people bad-mouth an overt reliance on tables, because they're cumbersome and outdated as a platform for full page design.  The first time you're handed a disastrous layout consisting of tables embedded within tables embedded within tables, and you're asked to make any improvements/changes/add content, you'll know exactly why people complain.  CSS is far better equipped for a layout as a whole.

That said, tables still have some good uses, and it would seem your current project is one of them.